# What is "make sure the owner of the folder is the Apache user (mostly it is www-data)"?

Tags: php, apache

I have a PHP script application installed on a cloud server.
One of the function is the "PDF Preview", which is currently not working properly.

I contacted the PHP script owner, and he asked me to make sure: 
1. dompdf/lib/font/ folder has write permissions (777)
2. the owner of the folder is the Apache user (mostly it is www-data)

For the 1st one, I tried to change the directory permission directly in the FileZilla interface. But it always changes back to 775 after I refresh...

For the 2nd one, I have no idea what it means... I contacted the technical support of my cloud server service. He said it's an App related issue, not server.

Can anyway give me some direction please? Should I use SSH? or anything else?

Really appreciated your help...

Erin

Comment: 775 for file permissions is probably best and I would leave the permissions at 775. Changing to 777 won't solve the problem. Changing ownership probably will solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have SSH access, it is easier.

1) SSH in and CD into your web directory (likely public_html)

2) run the command `chmod -R 777 dompdf/lib/font/`
However permission 755 is likely fine...

3) Run `ls -l`. It will likely look like this:

-rw-r--r-- 1 erin erin 395 Aug 21 2013 index.php

The first 'erin' is the user and the second 'erin' is the group.
There may be other files that have the correct group (such as www or apache). Try and match other files in the public_html directory:

To change the owner: `chown apache dompdf/lib/font/`

To change the group: `chgrp apache dompdf/lib/font/`

If you're on shared hosting you might not have access to do this. I'm guessing it's more likely a path or configuration issue than a permissions issue, but give this a shot.

Comment: Hi jordan,  I typed ls -l, and I got: drwxrwxrwx 2 abcdef www-data   4096 Aug 20 14:15 fonts    Then, I typed "chgrp Apache dompdf/lib/fonts" I got this: "                                                                                                
chgrp: invalid group: `Apache' "   Any ideas? Thank you so much!

Comment: www-data is fine and drwxrwxrwx is 777 so you should be good, what error are you seeing now?

Comment: I see. So it's 777 already...  But in my APP, when I hit "PDF Preview", I still see garbled text... The Script owner said, I need to make sure the owner of the folder is the Apache user instead of www-data... Is this the reason?

Comment: You mentioned that try to match other files in the public_html. When I do "ls -l" at public_html, all the directories have the same www-data group. Should I change everything to apache?  Or can I only change the dompdf/lib/font directory?Thank you!

Comment: No, I'd leave them all www-data and not use apache. There are different types of webhosts and some use apache and some use www-data. If they're set to www-data then that's correct.

Comment: Hi jordan, thank you very much for your help. I confirmed with the hosting provider and they said the www-data is an apache user:P  So, I will contact the PHP Script owner again and see what else I can do to fix the PDF preview problem. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you cannot change the owner of a file/directory via FTP.  You can via SSH.
The command to change file permissions:
    chmod 777 filename.php
To change a directory's permissions:

```
chmod -R 777 dirname/
```

To change the owner of a file:

```
chown www-data filename.php
```

To change the owner of a directory:

```
chown -R www-data dirname/
```

To change the group of a file:

```
chgrp www-data filename.php
```

To change the group of a directory:

```
chgrp -R www-data dirname/
```

Make sure you are in the file's directory when changing file permissions and ownership with the above commands. Otherwise you'll have to update the path.

If you are updating directories, be sure to be above the directory you wish to update.

Hope this helps.

P. S.  To view the current permissions / owner / group of a file or directory, use the `ls -la` command.

Comment: Thank you. This is helpful too:)

Answer (score 0):

Do not use the database user as the UNIX user. Use www-data.

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
```

There is a difference between the database user and the Apache user. The Apache User is the only one who can actually read the files. The database user is only meant for giving/taking database read/write permissions.

In addition, keep the default permissions from the webapp install. Do not change those, except for the owning user/group. If you are instructed by the webapp, change permissions.

If you are more concerned about security, you could instead run the following commands:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:www-data /var/www

sudo chmod -R 640 /var/www
```

This makes the actual files owned by your user, so that only you (and root) can modify them. The reason www-data is referenced is so that Apache can still READ the files, but not actually write to them.

The 640 allows you (the file owner) to read and write, while allowing the www-data group to read files. It also blocks anyone else from possibly reading the file contents.

(The above is only one possible (untested) method. More good ways are available [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/46371/208574).)